# OpenCV camera calibration rotation vector to matrix

Tags: python, c++, opencv, camera-calibration

Using the following tutorial for camera calibration, I was able to get a rotation vector and a translation vector. https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html

I get the relation between camera matrix and rotation/translation matrix but I can't figure out a way to traduce this rotation vector into a rotation matrix.

Moreover, I am trying to figure out how to get a projection matrix but I am not finding an openCV function to call for that.

Do you know a way for any of those points please ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

First, the theory of the camera model is quite dense but necessary to understand all of this. In case you are not use to it, here is a Wikipedia path to learn from the basis to the camera and transformation matrix:

- [Pinhole camera model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model)
- [Understanding homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates)
- [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) and
- [rotation matrix in 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)
- [3D projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) (perspective projection part)
- [Camera matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix)

Concerning OpenCV, there is a [function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective) to apply a perspective transformation called `warpPerspective`.

You can also take a look at all other function in the Geometric Transform module, there are very interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV function you are looking for is called [cv2.Rodrigues](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga61585db663d9da06b68e70cfbf6a1eac), which can be used to transform a rotation vector into a rotation matrix and vice versa. Alternatively, in Python, you can use [scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation), e.g.:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

rvec = [1,2,3]
rotation_object = Rotation.from_rotvec(rvec)
rotation_matrix = rotation_object.as_matrix()
```